# Is this an OK way to install Apache with SSL on CentOS 6?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, httpd, yum, centos6

I'm setting up a CentOS 6 server on a VPS. I've worked with Apache before, but I've never dealt with CentOS 6.

I guess it would just be this right?

```
sudo yum install httpd -y
sudo yum install mod_ssl -y
```

(And then use `chkconfig` to set it to run on startup and start configuring the details under `/etc/httpd/conf`.)

Is there more to it? Anything special I should be know about going in? Any gotchas I should be wary of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yum install -y mod_ssl 
is sufficient. It will install all required dependencies (including httpd).

After installation:
chkconfig httpd on